Kerberos double-hop issue
Okay, here's the scenario:

IIS running a web app on SERVERWEB as ServiceAccount.
Web app connects to SQL on SERVERSQL as ServiceAccount.
In SQL session, an SSIS package is executed. The SSIS package tries to connect to a network share on SERVERFILE. NTFS permissions allow ServiceAccount to connect. The SSIS package runs with the session credentials, i.e. ServiceAccount.
The connection to SERVERFILE fails. Event log on SERVERFILE shows that the connection was attempted with an anonymous login.

So, obviously a double hop issue, right? Where am I going wrong?

All servers and the service account are in the same domain.
Domain is running on Server 2016.
The service account is a gMSA.
I have run Set-ADAccountControl -identity ServiceAccount$ -TrustedForDelegation $true -TrustedToAuthForDelegation $false to enable unconstrained delegation.


What security principal on the SQL Server is executing the code that attempts to impersonate the Service account? Is it the local system/machine account? Or another service account? That's what needs to be trusted to delegate the credentials.

My understanding is that SSIS uses the user session to execute the package, so it should be the same service account that IIS is using.

Should be? That needs to be validated. It's likely the SQL computer account, unless you configured a domain user account for use on the SQL Server.

I have validated that the SSIS package is executing as ServiceAccount$.

The weird thing is that if I set an SPN like cifs/serverfile.domain.com serviceaccount$, it breaks every user's access to network shares on that server.

After trying all sorts of things, the answer ended up being "don't use a gmsa". I switched things to use a regular service account and it all just worked.
